# How to find a "flag base" to an endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found several exercises that ask me to find a flag base for a given matrix, for example:

$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 4 \\
-1 & -2 & -3 \end{array} \right)$$

I know that a flag base $B$ for $A$ exists iff $A$ is triangularizable; then I create the matrix $M$ with the columns being the vectors of $B$ and:

$$T=M^{-1}AM$$

where $T$ is finally triangular.

But I don't mind of $T$, I only need to build some $B$. How can I do that without make too many calculations?

I give you the Eigenspaces:

$$E_{-1}= span \left( \begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$$

$$E_{0}= span \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$$

Thank you very much, this is really important.

Comment: Iis a flag base of $A$ a flag that is stabilized by $A$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question. I tried to explain what I know about the flag. It's difficult to find much about that on the web or the books. But I'm preparing for the test of Tuesday and in the old tests I found several exercises that ask me to find the flag for a matrix. Sincerely I didn't realize very well what is it and especially how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the definition of flag basis you are looking for is: If $T$ is a linear transformation $T : V \to V$, then a *flag basis* for $T$ is a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ of $V$ such that
$$Tv_j = \sum_{i = 1}^j b_{ji} v_i$$
note that the summation is only taken up to $i = j$. This means that $T$ is triangular in the basis $\mathcal B$.

So, to find your basis $\mathcal B$ you need to find a basis in which $A$ is triangular. There are a couple of different methods to convert a matrix to triangular form, there is e.g. the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) and the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). I will describe how to get the basis for converting to Jordan normal form.

You have started calculating the eigenvectors for $A$, which is a good start. You calculated the following eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs:
$$\lambda_1 = 0, ~~~~ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\lambda_2 = -1, ~~~~ v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
but these don't make a basis since you don't have enough vectors.

Actually, if you look at the characteristic polynomial $p_A(x) = -x^3 -2x^2 -x$ of $A$ you see that it has a double root in $x = -1$, so there "should be" an additional eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$, but there isn't! The multiplicity of an eigenvalue in the characteristic polynomial is called the *algebraic multiplicity* of the eigenvalue, while the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace is called the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue. In this case the geometric multiplicity is smaller than the algebraic multiplicity, so we have to resort to a special trick.

Say there existed a vector $v_3$ such that $(A - \lambda_2I)v_3 = v_2$, then we would have
$$Av_3 = Av_3 - \lambda_2 I v_3 + \lambda_2 I v_3 =
(A - \lambda_2I)v_3 + \lambda_2 v_3 = v_2 + \lambda_2v_3
$$
such a vector $v_3$ is called a [generalized eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector). This would be sufficient for us to construct a flag basis.

Note that above we can just solve for $v_3$, so let's try it. We get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 -1 & -2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
v_3 = v_2
\Rightarrow
v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and we can verify that indeed $Av_3 = v_2 + \lambda_2v_3$.

So, then the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ constitute a flag basis since:
$$
\begin{align}
Av_1 &= 0 = 0 \cdot v_1 \\
Av_2 &= (-1)v_2 = 0 \cdot v_1 + (-1) \cdot v_2 \\
Av_3 &= v_2 + (-1)v_3 = 0 \cdot v_1 + 1 \cdot v_2 + (-1) \cdot v_3
\end{align}$$
so in each expansion of $Av_i$ we only have terms with $v_j$ where $j \leq i$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome.